# jQuery: Use a variable on animate property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using animate function, and I need to set the height property of the animation to match variable pituus, because the content height depends on form submit.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.kotisivut.name/quiz.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "text",
    error: function() {
        alert('Nyt jotakin meni kyllÃ¤ pahemman kerran pieleen. YritÃ¤ uudelleen?');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#resultcontainer").html(data);
        $("#service-test").fadeOut(1400);
        $("#resultcontainer").fadeIn(1500, function() {
            alert($("#page").height());
            var pituus = $("#page").height();
            $("#page").animate({
                "height": "pituus"
            }, 1600);
        });
    }
});​
```

However, it seems like I can't pass a variable there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes, change to:

```
$("#page").animate({
    height: pituus
}, 1600);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But there's still a problem. If I assign the container a fixed height, it won't animate, and if I don't it fixes the height before the animation is executed.

Comment: So is there a way to override that?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the string `"pituus"`.

Just replace:

```
            "height": "pituus"
```

with:

```
            "height": pituus
```

or, because you don't need quotes on the property unless it has spaces:

```
            height: pituus
```